# Java error when launching Pilon

Tags: assembly, reference-genome

I am trying to use Pilon to improve a reference based on some Illumina data I have got. So, I aligned the Illumina reads to the reference using bwa. Then, I want to use Pilon to improve the reference using the alignment file in BAM format.

Information about Pilon is found [here](https://github.com/broadinstitute/pilon/wiki/Requirements-&-Usage). I installed Pilon using conda.

The output of 'pilon' is:

```
Pilon version 1.22 Wed Mar 15 16:38:30 2017 -0400

    Usage: pilon --genome genome.fasta [--frags frags.bam] [--jumps jumps.bam] [--unpaired unpaired.bam]
                 [...other options...]
           pilon --help for option details
```

The output of:

```
pilon --genome ref.fa --frags readsSorted.bam --output pilo --outdir output/scaffold
```

is:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.run(Boot.java:340)
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.main(Boot.java:166)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.broadinstitute.pilon.GenomeRegion.<init>(GenomeRegion.scala:55)
    at org.broadinstitute.pilon.GenomeFile$$anonfun$contigRegions$1.apply(GenomeFile.scala:72)
 at org.broadinstitute.pilon.GenomeFile$$anonfun$contigRegions$1.apply(GenomeFile.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
 at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:160)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
 at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
 at org.broadinstitute.pilon.GenomeFile.contigRegions(GenomeFile.scala:72)
 at org.broadinstitute.pilon.GenomeFile$$anonfun$2.apply(GenomeFile.scala:52)
    at org.broadinstitute.pilon.GenomeFile$$anonfun$2.apply(GenomeFile.scala:52)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:277)
    at org.broadinstitute.pilon.GenomeFile.<init>(GenomeFile.scala:52)
    at org.broadinstitute.pilon.Pilon$.main(Pilon.scala:98)
    at org.broadinstitute.pilon.Pilon.main(Pilon.scala)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Note that the error is a memory issue:

`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like gringer already commented, the cause of your error is nicely given by the `java` program. Your default `max heap` settings are probably too low for the program. If you have more memory on your machine you can give `max heap` a higher value. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap) and answers on Stack overflow.

You'll probably need to use the `-Xmxn` argument in `java`.

Answer (score 0):

"If pilon was installed by condo, edit the file "/Users/user/anaconda/bin/pilon" by changing the maximum memory limit from 1G to higher numbers like "14G". It works. " 
check the thread: https://github.com/broadinstitute/pilon/issues/26